# Sort Posts By Custom Field Date

Tags: query-posts

I know it's not a new question, but everything I found fails to sort my posts.
 I simply want to sort 30 posts that have a custom field, let's say `album_date_sort`, by the date entered in its value. So the order will be by `meta_value`

The date in the meta value is in this format 2014-09-19 (I read that is the correct format)

I tried this:

```
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'meta_key' => 'album_date_sort', 'order_by' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );  ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li><?php the_title( '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a>' ); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

the sorting is not right - it doesn't order by meta_value date, nor post date, they are messed up.

```
 <?php query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=30&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=album_date_sort&order=ASC'); ?>
```

same bad sorting again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "sorting is not right". Please [edit] your question an explain what is currently happening

Comment: sorry, I had no idea it matters, since it is not doing the job...edited.